# Can NSScrollView scroll if setHasHorizontalScroller:NO?

Tags: cocoa, nsscrollview, nsscroller

Is it possible to 'hide' the scrollers of an NSScrollView and still get gestural scrolling behavior?

Answer (score 4):

Create an NSScroller subclass and set it as the vertical/horizontal scroller for the NSScrollView instance.

The NSScroller subclass should override this (10.7 and above):

```
+ (CGFloat)scrollerWidthForControlSize:(NSControlSize)controlSize scrollerStyle:(NSScrollerStyle)scrollerStyle {
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely a bug in AppKit. I was able to get this working on 10.8.5 using either of the following solutions:

**1)** Subclass NSScroller (preferred method)

```
+ (BOOL)isCompatibleWithOverlayScrollers
{
    // Let this scroller sit on top of the content view, rather than next to it.
    return YES;
}

- (void)setHidden:(BOOL)flag
{
    // Ugly hack: make sure we are always hidden.
    [super setHidden:YES];
}
```

**Source**: [jmk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1707765/jmk) in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12960795/836263

**2)** Bounce-back and momentum seems broken when using the legacy style. It also partially breaks Apple's [scroll synchronization](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/SynchroScroll.html) code. It causes the scroll views to reset scroll position if one is `NSScrollerStyleOverlay` and the other is `NSScrollerStyleLegacy`. If the overlay-style scroll view is scrolled, then the legacy style is scrolled, it resets both scroll views to the top y=0 scroll offset.

```
[self.scrollView setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
[self.scrollView setScrollerStyle:NSScrollerStyleLegacy];
[self.scrollView setHasVerticalScroller:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

Causes the scrollview to not display a scroller and not respond to gestural scrolling:

```
-setHasHorizontalScroller:NO
```

Causes a disabled scroller to be displayed, but it responds to gestural scrolling:

```
-setHasHorizontalScroller:YES
-setHidden:YES
```

Comment: I think maybe you mean "YES causes a disabled scroller **NOT** to be displayed, but it responds to gestural scrolling", no?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Try this soon after initializing the scrollView.

```
    self.scrollView.wantsLayer = YES;
```

I've gotten this to work without hiding an `NSScroller` subclass and without touching `setHasVerticalScroller:`. Also, if `self.scrollView` is a subclass that overrides `drawRect:`, try turning that off to make sure that what you're doing there isn't causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just try it?

To answer the question: Yes, if the user has mouse with a scroll wheel or a a scrolling-capable touchpad, it is still possible to scroll the view, despite the scrollers being invisible.

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I can scroll with my trackpad when setHasHorizontalScroller:YES, but not if setHasHorizontalScroller:NO.